# sonarqube xpath rule match multiple file patterns

Tags: xpath, sonarqube

I'am building custom rules in SonarQube 5.1.2 and I can't find out how to apply a rule to multiple file types.
I've seen that ant-style file pattern is only one pattern, not a list.

Specifically I want my rule to match `**/*.wsdl` and `**/*.WSDL` and eventually files with other extensions.

Is there a better way to do this than replicating the rule?

thanks.